# Show PHP application trace in Apache error log

Tags: php, apache, symfony1, logging

I have developed an application in PHP (using the Symfony framework).

My Apache error log file is getting full of these kind of errors:

```
[Mon Feb 13 20:08:08 2012] [error] [client 60.169.75.168] Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/." (/)., referer: http://www.mywebsite.com/account.php
[Mon Feb 13 20:08:10 2012] [error] [client 60.169.75.168] Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/." (/)., referer: http://www.mywebsite.com/services
```

Is there anyway I can get the Apache log to show a stack trace so that I can track down the problem?

Maybe I should tell Symfony (which is the guy writing some error messages to the log) to write something more (the error trace). Can it be that?

**UPDATE:** The problem occurs on production, thus I can't use xdebug.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can have xdebug only output to log files and not to the users, other than that why can't you install it on your production machine?

Comment: Internal policies make it very troublesome to install new software on the server.

Comment: I have noticed some production servers I've worked with having it pre-installed but disabled in config, have you checked to see if it's there already?

Comment: @Alex. Good thinking - it is not there already, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, well I don't think php has the ability to do stack traces without installing any extensions, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your settings.yml config file in apps/YOUR_APP/config/settings.yml for your prod environnement:

```
prod:
  .settings:
    logging_enabled: true
```

In your factories.yml config file in apps/YOUR_APP/config/factories.yml:

```
prod:
  logger:
    class: sfAggregateLogger
    param:
      level: debug
```

Remember to clear your cache.

```
php symfony cc
```

Symfony will write a more complete log of every request in its own log file (usualy in SYMFONY_DIR/log/YOUR_APP_prod.log)

Answer (score 1):

There is a PHP extension called xDebug that I believe will do what you want, it won't place the stack trace in the apache logs though, you need to specify where to store them.

Comment: [http://xdebug.org/](http://xdebug.org/) and you will need wincachegrind or kcachegrind to read the files.

Comment: The problem is that the issue happens only on a production machine - thus I can't install XDebug

Answer (score 0):

`to show a stack trace`

You do not need it. This message is generated by the Symfony Framework, which just tells you that it does not know anything about modules `account.php` or `services`. These modules are requested by shown URLs:

http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/04-The-Basics-of-Page-Creation

> **URLs are part of the response**
>
> Symfony contains a routing system that allows you to have a complete
>   separation between the actual action name and the form of the URL
>   needed to call it. This allows for custom formatting of the URL as if
>   it were part of the response. You are no longer limited by the file
>   structure nor by the request parameters; the URL for an action can
>   look like the phrase you want. For instance, the call to the index
>   action of a module called article usually looks like this:
>   http://localhost/frontend_dev.php/article/index?id=123
>
> This URL
>   retrieves a given article from a database. In this example, it
>   retrieves an article (with id=123) in the Europe section that
>   specifically discusses finance in France. But the URL can be written
>   in a completely different way with a simple change in the routing.yml
>   configuration file:
>   http://localhost/articles/europe/france/finance.html
>
> Not only is the
>   resulting URL search engine-friendly, it is also significant for the
>   user, who can then use the address bar as a pseudo command line to do
>   custom queries, as in the following:
>   http://localhost/articles/tagged/finance+france+euro
>
> Symfony knows how
>   to parse and generate smart URLs for the user. The routing system
>   automatically peels the request parameters from a smart URL and makes
>   them available to the action. It also formats the hyperlinks included
>   in the response so that they look "smart". You will learn more about
>   this feature in Chapter 9. Overall, this means that the way you name
>   the actions of your applications should not be influenced by the way
>   the URL used to call them should look, but by the actions' functions
>   in the application. An action name explains what the action actually
>   does, and it is often a verb in the infinitive form (like show, list,
>   edit, and so on). Action names can be made totally invisible to the
>   end user, so don't hesitate to use explicit action names (like
>   listByName or showWithComments). You will economize on code comments
>   to explain your action function, plus the code will be much easier to
>   read.

Comment: Hi Cheery. You are right - those messages are generated by Symfony. The fact is those URL DO exist (I am going to update my question). There must be some plugin that is trying to do something wrong but I can't figure out which plugin or what code.
Infact you can see in the error messages I pasted the URL is "/." - that's pretty strange.

Comment: @dan  But there is no `backtrace` in your situation (when some plugin is doing something wrong). The first thing you should do is to check the referer for those requests, it will give you the idea where they are coming from.

Comment: why isn't there backtrace in my case? Isn't there some code calling the code generating the error?

Comment: @dan What do you hope to find with it? You will see where that message comes from - from the framework's system module which was unable to find module by the requested url. Is it going to help you? I do not think so.

Comment: that will help me understand which module is buggy so that I can disable/fix it - amn't I right?

Comment: @dan I do not think so. Why do you think that the backtrace should contain information about this module? Or do you want to find which module generates those links?

Comment: that's what I need: to know which module/plugin is trying to load the URL "/." which leads to the error. How do you think I can achieve that?

Comment: @dan Check the html code of the referring page. You'll find the `/.` links, check what generates them. When you were talking the backtrace I assumed it is was about the backtrace at the moment when the message in the logs is generated, which, of course, will not provide any interesting information.